# Sharepoint DataFormWebPart get in code behind the result XML

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I got a DataFormWebPart
and as we know he creates us an xml that we usually get there in our xsl like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/" >
<xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row">
```

Moreover, say we want to put something else in our XML we will do this

```
public override void DataBind()
{
        this.sourceDoc = new ChannelsDFWP_XmlCreator().CreateXmlDoc(-ChannelsDAL.DAYSDELTA);
        this.BindXmlData();
 }
```

Now if we just want some extra params we'll do this

```
protected override void ModifyXsltArgumentList(ArgumentClassWrapper argList)
        {
            argList.AddParameter("name", string.Empty, value);
            base.ModifyXsltArgumentList(argList);
        }
```

Now I want to do something in the middle, I want the same XML result I get by default and extend this like this

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(the same xml as the DFWP renders it);
XmlNode root = _ xmlDoc.CreateElement("anotherNode");
```

and then return it all. you might this about this

```
var xml = Lists.ChannelsCategories.Instance.GetList(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb).Items.Xml;
```

But this brings a totally different (and more ugly) XML. If you could even just tell me where is the XSL to transform it to what we know i would be happy as well :)

THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is that it's not exactly possible.

But there is hope - **SharePoint:AggregateDataSource** did the job for me since my other data was in another list

Basically the SharePoint:AggregateDataSource accepts IDataSource do i guess (and hope to try) that you can add there all sorts of data with the right class.

Here is some more info http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/dataformwebpart-add-data-to-xml.html